# How to force Mathematica to simplify this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression
$$2^{1-2 n^2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^{-n-1} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)^{n (n+1)} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^{n^2}$$

This can be simplified to
$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)^{n+2}$$

But

```
 FullSimplify[2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*(1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2, n > 0]
```

returns unevaluated

Interestingly, the ratio of these two expressions is simplified:

```
FullSimplify[2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*((1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2 / ((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^(n + 2)), n > 0]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[Table[2^(1-2 n^2) (3-√5)^(-1-n) (-1+√5)^(n (1+n)) (1+√5)^n^2,{n,10}],n]//FullSimplify` gives `2^(-1-n) (1+√5)^n (3+√5)`.

Comment: Also `FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[2^(1 - 2 n^2) (3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n) (-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n (1 + n)) (1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2]]` gives the same result, but such a result is only partial, not the best simplification.

Comment: @chyanog - You can get closer by putting the simplification within the `Table`. That is, 
 `FindSequenceFunction[Table[(2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*(1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2) // Simplify, {n, 1, 10}], n]` evaluates to `(2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^(1 - n)* (2 + Sqrt[5])` Or you get the same result with `FindSequenceFunction[Table[(2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*(1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2), {n, 1, 10}] // Simplify, n]` As a general rule you want to provide `FindSequenceFunction` with the simplest form to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves my problem:

```
Simplify[FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[
2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + 
Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*(1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2]] /. {1 + Sqrt[5] -> 
2 GoldenRatio, 3 + Sqrt[5] -> 2*GoldenRatio^2}]

 (* GoldenRatio^(2 + n) *)
```

However in general, Mathematica is not very successful in simplifying expressions containing GoldenRatio. I had to supplement the knowledge base with substitutions.

Thank you all for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

That's where I can bring it:

```
expr1 = 2^(1 - 2*n^2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n)*(-1 + 
      Sqrt[5])^(n*(1 + n))*(1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2;
expr2 = expr1 /. (-1 + Sqrt[5])^(n (1 + n)) -> a*(-1 + Sqrt[5])^n^2 //
    Simplify;
expr3 = expr2 /. a -> (-1 + Sqrt[5])^n;
expr4 = expr3 /. (3 - Sqrt[5])^(-1 - n) -> a*(3 - Sqrt[5])^-n // 
   Simplify[#, n > 0] &;
expr5 = expr4 /. a -> (3 - Sqrt[5])^-1;
expr6 = Simplify[expr5/(3 + Sqrt[5]), n > 0]*(3 + Sqrt[5])

 (*   2^(-1 - n) (1 + Sqrt[5])^n (3 + Sqrt[5])   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: OK, but this is only a partial success. See the two comments above, with the same result. I'd like to see an expression `((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^(n+2)` or `GoldenRatio^(n+2)`.

Comment: So far, the most elegant result `(* GoldenRatio^n (1 + GoldenRatio) *)` is obtained by using substitution `2^(-1 - n) (1 + Sqrt[5])^n (3 + Sqrt[5]) /. Sqrt[5] -> 2 GoldenRatio - 1 // FullSimplify`. Does anyone get GoldenRatio^(n+2) from this?